# How to open a html file whenever it is modified?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am faced with the issue of IIS express stopping abruptly without any stack trace while debugging in local.

[image]

I have found a work around for this by writing the stack trace to a html file.

```
string file = @"C:\Users\INLASKD\Desktop\ExceptionHandlerError.html";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
{
   using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
     {
        w.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
     }
}
```

Now, I want to open this ExceptionHandlerError.html automatically everytime its modified when IIS Express stops.

I want bat file or a script to automate this. How can I go about this?

Note: I am connected to a network that doesn't allow administrator access and can't access event viewer.

Comment: The `cmd` console isn't really event-driven.  It'd be better to have your exception handler launch the html file after writing the stack trace I think.  Monitoring the file for size changes via batch script isn't the most graceful solution I don't think.

Comment: Hmmm.  How do I do that?

Comment: Not sure.  I didn't know IIS Express let you write your own exception handler before you asked your question.  Indeed, I didn't know IIS Express was crashy before you asked your question.  `:)`  That's C# code, isn't it?  I'd guess below the `using` code blocks you'd create a `new Process()` object, populate its `StartInfo` properties, and then invoke its `Start()` method.  But that's all a wild guess.  I haven't written much in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I was able to open the browser right after writing it to the file with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);
```

Final code is as below:

```
    string file = @"C:\Users\iraacn-9ajm\Desktop\ExceptionHandlerError.html";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
    {
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
           {
           w.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
           }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this:

```
@echo off
set "file=C:\Users\INLASKD\Desktop\ExceptionHandlerError.html"
:loop
attrib "%file%" | findstr /B /L A 1>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
::open the file here
start "" "%file%"
attrib -A "%file%"
)
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
goto loop
```

Comment: Thanks. But will this bat file keep running always? without it being placed inside scheduler?

Comment: Yes, although I forgot to edit the archive attribute, so I just fixed that.